# Nonlinear Function of two variables

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I need a general equation that I can use to model the nonlinear or exponential relationship between a variable Y and two predictor variables X1 and X2. My sketch below shows the type of relationship I am looking for. Note that all three variables range between 0 and 1.

[image: Type of Relationship I need]

Comment: You must be more specific about the direction of the tangents at the endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $y = x_1^{\frac{1}{2}x_2 + 2(1-x_2)}$. The exponent needs some reparametrization though, in case you want to have a $y = x_1$ when $x_2=1/2$...

Comment: Many thanks PrudiiArca! It is not that important to me that Y = x1 when x2 = 1/2; I wanted a bit more curvature in the curves than what your equation provided, so I added a constant K before the 1/2 and 2 in your equation, with K = 0.8 when X2 > 0.5 and 0.5 when X2 <= 0.5. This works fine for me. Thanks again!

Comment: You are very welcome! Glad I could help :)